# Tunneling trough VPN over TCP

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, tcp

I'm currently trying to set up a VPN on my server to connect to from my Laptop.
The server is a command-line ubuntu running on a x64 machine. The Laptop runs x64 Windows 7.

The VPN itself is already working. I use OpenVPN 2.3, and with default settings (UDP connection on port 1194) I can connect from my laptop to the server.

But: I want to be able to conenct via TCP. I tried switching the settings to `proto tcp` and port 443, but the client couldn't establish a connection. Sadly it didn't give me ANY output at all. I tried another port too, with no success. The [Ubuntu-Users Wiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/OpenVPN#Microsoft-Windows) lists the possibility to get a tcp connection over tcp 443 with a local proxy server, but this also didn't work for me.

In the second step, I want all my connections to go trough this vpn tunneling. That's also something where I haven't really a grip on how to do this... Basically, I want to be able to use udp ports trough tcp.

I'm not really into network stuff, so could you please help me out? If you need any information, please comment and I'll edit my post.

---

EDIT: Problem 1 could be fixed by just restarting the windows...

Comment: Things to check:  1. Is there already something listening on port 443 (ie. web server)?  2. You changed the config on both the client and server and restarted the server?  3. Make sure logging is enabled (config `verb` >= 3 on both sides) and check the log files.

Comment: Yeah, there was a webserver running on 443, that's why i tried out another port, but it still didn't work
I'll try out the verbose option (:

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean by *use udp ports through tcp*.  You're wanting to send UDP traffic over the VPN that uses a TCP connection, is that right?

Comment: @heavyd exactly that's the point

Comment: @heavyd My client logs some confusing stuff, i edited my question with the log

Comment: Did you update your client config with `proto tcp`?  It looks like its still trying to use UDP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20778/discussion-between-heavyd-and-florian-koch).